# How do I show missing icons in the system tray?

Tags: icons, camera, system-tray

I have two programs; Retroshare and cameramonitor (which are both great programs) that will not show in the system tray. It's frustrating.

Comment: Note that RetroShare might have some security issues http://specialmeaning.blogspot.com/2016/09/retroshare-scandal-of-free-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the system you have. Having similar problem in Ubuntu 12.04 Unity I found:

1. Terminal command `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist` shows the list of applications allowed to use systray.
2. `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist <whitelist>` changes the list to wanted whitelist (the syntax is obvious by the result of the previous one; you may check the result with it)
3. Application Alltray changes the effect of close of the window to close to systray.

Be cautious! For me, it worked fine for Skype, but using the 3rd option resulted in a stupid behaviour in case of Firefox (open from systray opens the application, but menu only with hidden window and some features aren't working - I still fight against it).

Comment: By proposition of Pieter I solved the "stupid behaviour" problem with new profile.